# How to test config file changes?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I wrote function which changes values in config/app.php using file_put_content.

```
    public function updateConfig($path, $key, $value)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($path);
        $pattern = "/'" . $key . "' => '[0-9]+'/";
        $replacement = "'" . $key . "' => '" . $value . "'";
        $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

        file_put_contents($path, $content);
    }
```

```
$path = base_path() . '/config/app.php';
$key = 'version_number';
$value = '10';
$service->updateConfig($path, $key, $value);
$this->assertEquals(config('app.version_number'), $value);
```

How can I test it with changing config file?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to change the config then use it.
There is a way you can achieve this without editing the config file. Note that, in order to speed up Laravel, configurations are cached and you need to run `php artisan clear:cache` or manually delete cache files.

If you want to change config on the fly. Change it as shown before using it.

`Config::set('app.version_number', 10);`

Comment: I want to update config once when a new version comes out and then use it e.g. for bugsnag